# No buildable go source files after update Goland to EAP 19

Tags: go, goland

After I updated **[GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/)** from ***EAP 18*** to ***EAP 19*** my imports are red and these errors occur in each file:

[image: Import errors]

My *$GOROOT* and *$GOPATH* are the same as before. *$GOROOT* points to `/usr/local/go.` Files are buildable through shell but GoLand keep showing errors.

I am running GoLand on Mac OS with **Go version** `go1.9.1 darwin/amd64`:

> GoLand (1.0 Preview) 1.0 EAP
>   Build #GO-173.3727.24, built on November 16, 2017
>   GoLand EAP User
>   Expiration date: December 16, 2017
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b6 x86_64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   Mac OS X 10.12.6

Comment: Where do Goroot and Gopath point?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky GOROOT= **usr/local/go** and GOPATH= **/Users/raca/GoglandProjects** which is my standard gopath

Comment: Looks like Goland has lost them or messed. Try to check them in goland glibal settings or project’s.

Comment: Are there non-test files in `flag` package? How the editor looks when you open them?

Comment: @AlexanderZolotov there is flag.go file. all files look OK

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky there is no project settings anymore in GoLand, but global settings look OK. It also shows GOROOT and GOPATH are set correctly

Comment: @IvanAracki, unfortunately, this is not enough for diagnosis. Please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com and attach logs (`Help | Compress logs and show in <file browser>`) and a screenshot of the editor with opened `flag.go` file.

Comment: @IvanAracki When I run anything with Goland, it shows me config in first lines. Like this:   ```GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.2/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/e.lisitsky/go #gosetup
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.2/libexec/bin/go generate /Users/e.lisitsky/go/src/github.com/looplab/fsm/fsm.go #gosetup
``` . Could you check it pls?

Comment: I am also having this exact problem on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Having the same problem on Ubuntu 17.10 after updating Goland

Comment: Have sae issue on Ubuntu 16.04, after updating go ide

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like indexes are corrupted. `File | Invalidate Caches` should help.

Comment: doesn't help for me. Also have several projects that builds nicely but one of libs in import sections is underlined with red in IDE with the eroror that there is no buildable go files.. even with the fact that it is in vendor folder of each projects

Comment: Altenrion, then it makes sense to file an issue about it with diagnostic details such as IDE version, project structure and screenshots: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 1):

When `File | Invalidate Caches` doesn't help, deleting the project and checking it out again does did the trick in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If invalidating caches does not fix the problem for you, it can also be that the package has build constraints that prevent it from being built on your system. I was attempting to import `golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc` while using Goland on a Mac and it took me a while to realize why Goland was saying it didn't have sources files when clearly it did. All the files in the `golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc` package are constrained to only build on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

One day I started to get this error on `GoLand 2018.1`

`GOROOT` & `GOPATH` where fine.

To fix that:

- Opened `File -> Settings -> Go -> GOPATH`
- Marked `Index entire GOPATH`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try these step:

1. close the goland IDE.
2. delete the .idea folder.
3. start the goland IDE.